# Adding 1 to an address result in adding 0xE0 to that address

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-address

I encountered a really weird behavior while trying to add an offset to an address which I got with the use of `&` operator.
So when I try to add any number to that address, the result is that adddress plus my number times `0xE0` (224).

[image: Offset 0]

[image: Offset 1]

[image: Offset 2]

These are screenshots of the watch list in Visual Studio.
The first row of each screenshot is the access of the address of my object, which is correct.
The second row is the same access, but we add the variable offset to it.
The third row is just the offset itself.

As you can see, everything is fine on the 1st screenshot. But on the second one, the addition is of `0xE0` (`0xE38-0xD58=0x0E0`) and not 1 as it should be. And on the last screenshot the addition is of `0x1C0` which is `2*0xE0`.

On the 2nd row, I expected to see `0x00000255ef9bed58` in the first screenshot, `0x00000255ef9bed59` in the second one and `0x00000255ef9bed5a` in the last one.

Comment: This is called the pointer arithmetic.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this, start by compiling and running the following code (C++, though I've included the C lines as comments if you want to use that language):

```
#include <iostream>                 // #include <stdio.h>
int main() {                        // int main(void) {
    int xyzzy[2];
    int *pXyzzy = &xyzzy[0];
    std::cout << pXyzzy << '\n';    // printf("%p\n", pXyzzy);
    pXyzzy = pXyzzy + 1;
    std::cout << pXyzzy << '\n';    // printf("%p\n", pXyzzy);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that will be something like (with my comments added):

```
0x7fffc9ef1150
0x7fffc9ef1154  // four bytes on
```

That's a *clear* difference of four bytes despite the fact that all you did was add *one* to the address between the two outputs.

That's because *pointer arithmetic is scaled based on the size of the thing you're pointing at.* In other words, adding one doesn't add one byte, it adds `X` bytes where `X` is (in this case) `4`, the size of an `int`.

Exactly the same thing is happening in your debugger session since it would be disconcerting (and rather painful to debug) if the compiler and debugger disagreed on how expressions were evaluated). If you were to print out the size of the structure you're adding one to, you will find it is `0xe0` bytes long.

If you *really* wanted to add one byte, you need to tell the compiler to *treat* it as something with a size of one byte, something like:

```
pXyzzy = (int*)((char*)pXyzzy + 1);
```

This results in:

```
0x7fffdbd74000
0x7fffdbd74001 // one byte on
```

Answer (score 5):

Pointers are not integers. Pointer arithmetic is different from integer arithmetic. Adding 1 to a pointer does not mean "give me the neighboring address". Adding 1 to a pointer means "give me the address of the neighbouring object within the array". The distance between neighbouring objects is same as the size of the object.  If that size is larger than a byte, then the neighboring object is several bytes away.

In this case if your calculation is correct, the size of the pointed object is 0xE0 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Given `t *my_ptr = get_a_pointer_somehow();` and `int my_num = get_a_number_somehow();`, when you do `my_ptr += my_num`, it advances the pointer by `my_num` of `t`, or in other words, adds `my_num * sizeof(t)` bytes to it. If you don't want that behavior, then cast the pointer to a `char *` first, since `sizeof(char)` is always 1.